# A messaging system on elasticsearch

Tags: database-design, architecture, elasticsearch

We’re building a messaging system where a message is distributed between multiple lists. Our current implementation is built on redis and looks something like this:

```
Message comes in from user “peeter”
Message is added to list “user:peeter:messages”
Since peeter is in the group “developers” the message is also added to “group:developer:messages” list
Since the group developers belongs to a watchlist (a group of groups) called “it”, the message is also added to "watchlist:it:messages" list
```

Now we have a new requirement, lists need to have filters attached to them. So the group "developers" would have a filter "+php -javascript" to show only messages from users in that group that matches that filter.

We thought about moving the entire thing over to elasticsearch. So we would index our messages in the following format:

```
{ 
    message : "PHP is awesome and Javascript is awesome and Java is awesome",
    user : "peeter",
    groups : ["developers", "architects"],
    watchlists : ["it", "tech personel", "weekend workers", "emergency staff"]
}
```

And when we're looking up the "developers" group we'd query elastic in the following format:

```
{ 
    query_string : "+php -javascript",
    term : {
        "groups" : "developers"
    }
}
```

The problem is these lists change rather often. New users are added to the "developer" group and new groups are added to the watchlists. You can also merge 2 groups together, so "developers" and "architects" become 
a single group called "dev-architects". We would be left with an index that is constantly being updated while heavily read.

The second idea we had was to index the document in the following format:

```
{ 
    message : "PHP is awesome and Javascript is awesome and Java is awesome",
    user : "peeter"
}
```

And when we're looking up the "developers" group we'd query elastic in the following format:

```
{ 
    query_string : "+php -javascript",
    term : {
        "user" : "peeter", "michael", "jamie"
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that there could be up to 2000 users in the group "developers".

Are either of these solutions valid?

Comment: Doesn't logstash (http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash), build on top of (and since some months part of ) ES already provide most/all of the stuff you need?

Comment: This isn't for log file management.

Comment: yeah, I realize that, but aren't log-entries and event-messages conceptually similar? Anyway, on second though I don't think it's that good a combi, since you need the 'watchlist' concept.

Answer (score 0):

A way to improve the performance of querying with the list of users belonging to the "developers" group could be using the terms lookup mechanism - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html#_terms_lookup_mechanism

So you can have a separate index (or type), containing a document for each group. In that document you hold the list of users that belong to that group. And you point your terms query to brings the terms to match from that document.

Can probably work the same with your watchlist terms.